# SAS Planet cache map (.sqlitedb) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I want to use SAS Planet map format in QGIS application.

[image]

SAS Planet has a file system like this and each zoom layer has their own subfolders. Eventually there is a SQLite DB to store the images like this.

[image]

Is there any way that I can use maps in my QGIS application (I am using QGIS C++ API). I have tried using SpatialLite but couldn't succeed.